# Will select exists(select from table where condition) return a 0 or a 1?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I'm just trying to find a way to check if a value exists in a very small table. Will this work? There are a lot of more complicated answers involving cases, but I was hoping I could just do this.

Are there edge cases I'm not thinking of or is my logic just bad?

EDIT: It's through JPQL so the SQL commands still available using that.

If the table contained users:

```
Harry
Charles
Nancy
```

And someone put in the user name Charles it should return true, if someone put in Bob it should return false (0 and 1 substitutable for false and true respectively)

Comment: which sql language are you talking about?

Comment: 1). Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful. 2). Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: In standard SQL `exists()` returns a `boolean` but not all DBMS products support a real boolean data type. But as you seem to be concerned about what JPQL does, not SQL, I removed the `sql` tag

Comment: EXISTS is boolean in JPQL. 0 and 1 are not boolean